# Bootstrap working on desktop but not on phone

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

I'm making my first website. Here is the code on pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/AuY95D8S

Here is some code to bypass the error notification.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="intro">
```

(I am so sorry for linking pastebin but it is a lot of code. Please understand that trying too format it here was way to time consuming and pastebin highlights html elements anyways)

On my desktop bootstrap works perfectly and resizes as it should. Here is a short video of how it resizes correctly.

https://streamable.com/gq9fv

In regular view mode (the first part of the video) the elements are aligned correctly. When I go into responsive design mode, the elements also align correctly.

But when I upload the website to my server, and test it out on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge), the elements align incorrectly.

Android Firefox:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awddh.png

Android Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGpa.png

As you can see, the elements align as if they were in the phone browsers desktop view mode (which it wasn't).

I tried this on someone else's phone and the same thing happened.

Is this a bootstrap bug? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Your code is not good. If your layout is liquid(full width) type. you don't need to add container-fluid. please simple use container class instead of container-fluid. And avoid to use BR tags.

Answer (score 3):

you should include  viewport element on your code,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to use col-lg-# instead of sm or xs. I guess the display on my phone is actually a different resolution from the Mozilla web tools.